# Calculating SNR of RF Waveform

Tags: noise, snr

I am trying to calculate the signal to noise ratio of this signal. I'm aware that the SNR calculation should be

$$SNR_{db} = 10\log_{10}\frac{P_s}{P_n}$$

For the noise signal $w[n]$ I'm using the formula $P_n = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N \big\lvert w[n]\big\rvert^2$ and the same for $P_s$.

My problem is that there seems to be a DC offset in the amplitude of my signal

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any actual noise here before the signal it just sits at an offset above zero. My signal is stored as quadrature samples and I don't know the proper way to get rid of the offset so I can calculate SNR properly.

Comment: It seems you don't know how the signal is generated, and you are making assumptions about signal properties (such as zero DC) that may be unwarranted. So, first step, find out more about the signal and potential sources of distortion. Only then should you worry about processing the signal.